# Can the input of this hash function be calculated based on the output?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

I have the following hash function and I am wondering if there is a way to calculate the input of this function based on the hashed value. Thanks in advance

```
def hash(message):
    key = [0x0f, 0xff, 0x00]
    for char in message:
        n = ord(char)
        key[0] ^= n
        key[1] &= n
        key[2] |= n
    return ’’ + chr(key[0]) + chr(key[1]) + chr(key[2])
```

Comment: what do you mean by **calculate the input**? what calculation do you want?

Comment: If it were possible to restore the original input from the 3 character output hash, you would've invented the world's best compression algorithm.

Comment: What does your analysis tell you?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, **no**. No meaningful hash function can be applied in reverse.

What hash functions do is that they try to create a "signature" of the original message. The signature must be small enough, and is usually used for verification or as an index into some storage.

To this end, the output domain must be significantly smaller than the input domain, or in other words, multiple inputs could correspond to the same output. In your case, strings `"000"` and `"000000000"` will have the same hash value, and you will have no way of distinguishing one from the other given just the hash.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of second pre-image of a hash function; there are infinitely many solutions for any hash function as long as you have enough the time and money.

Now assuming that, you had the time and money, and generated all possible second pre-images of the given hash value up to n-bit, and say we have x solutions.

```
for i in space(1..2^n)
   check hash(i) == TheHash
```

Even x=2, the attacker will not be able to determine the real pre-image that was output the hash. Keep, however, in mind that, from the point of attacking, the attacker already find x solutions to break your hash.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is infeasible to generate a message from its hash value except by trying all possible messages.